# Xcode Plugin Context Menu

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to add items to the context menu in Xcode with a plugin. To do this, I created a right click mouse event and used it as a parameter for the menuForEvent method of the contentView of the mainWindow. The context menu is never initialized. The mouse click event is initialized, but I'm not sure if it's initialized correctly. My code is below. Am I at least on the right track? Thanks in advance.

```
NSEvent* mouseClickEvent =[NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSRightMouseDown location:[NSEvent mouseLocation] modifierFlags:[NSEvent modifierFlags] timestamp:NSTimeIntervalSince1970 windowNumber:[[NSApp mainWindow] windowNumber] context:[[NSApp mainWindow] graphicsContext] eventNumber:0 clickCount:1 pressure:1.0];
NSMenu* rightClickContextMenu = [[[NSApp mainWindow] contentView] menuForEvent: mouseClickEvent];
```